# Extract all the XML entry key values as rows using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I'm trying to extract the key values (1,2,3) from a single row in a table, but I'm only able to extract a single row at a time using what I know:

```
cast([attributes] as XML).value('(//Map/entry[@key="catalogItem"]/value/Map/entry/@key)[1]','VARCHAR(20)')
```

Depending on what number I put in the [x] I get that entry.
I tried removing the [x] and got the error: XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

```
            <Map>
               <entry key="catalogItem">
                 <value>
                   <Map>
                     <entry key="1" value="x"/>
                     <entry key="2" value="y"/>
                     <entry key="3" value="z"/>
```

I want the results to be a single column

1

2

3

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

A combination of XQuery methods `.nodes()` and `.value()` gives what you need.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, XMLColumn XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (XMLColumn) VALUES
(N'<Map>
    <entry key="catalogItem">
        <value>
            <Map>
                <entry key="1" value="x"/>
                <entry key="2" value="y"/>
                <entry key="3" value="z"/>
            </Map>
        </value>
    </entry>
</Map>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.* 
    , c.value('@key', 'INT') AS [key]
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY XMLColumn.nodes('/Map/entry/value/Map/entry') AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| id | key |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |